# RestResource extracting array from JSON packet

Tags: apex, rest-api, json, rest, get

I am currently receving a `JSON` packet from an external server and placing the values in variables for further use. The `JSON` packet has an array that can and will grow depending on the amount of assets being sent over. I am not able to `get` any of the values from the array to place in any of my other variables.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/assets')

global with sharing class asset_REST_controller {

@HttpPost
global static void doPost(String jsonPayload) {

        String sf_ord_num;
        String asset_id;
        String product_code;
        String product_descrip;
        String serial_numb;                             
        String start_date_raw;
        Datetime start_date;
        List<Object> asset_info;                             


        Map<String, Object> deserialized_response = 
            (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonPayload);

        sf_order_number = 
            (String)deserialized_response.get('sf_order_num');                             

        start_date_raw = 
            (String)deserialized_response.get('start_date');

        start_date = 
            (Datetime)JSON.deserialize('"' + start_date_raw + '"', DateTime.class);

        asset_info = (List<Object>)deserialized_response.get('asset_info');

    }

}
```

The incoming `JSON` packet looks like this:

```
jsonPayload: {"sf_ord_numb":"12345","start_date":"2020-01-15T00:00:00Z","asset_info":[{"product_code":"TEST","product_descrip":"This is a test","asset_id":"01543234321234","serial-numb":""}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast each element in the List to a `Map<String, Object>` to continue processing.

```
for(Object assetObject: asset_info) {
  Map<String, Object> asset = (Map<String, Object>)assetObject;
  String product_code = (String)asset.get('product_code');
  // ... etc ... //
}
```

You'll probably want to write a class to hold this data, because it's a list:

```
public class AssetData {
  public String product_code, product_description, ...;
}
```

...

```
List<AssetData> assets = new List<AssetData>();
for(Object assetObject: asset_info) {
  Map<String, Object> asset = (Map<String, Object>)assetObject;
  AssetData data = new AssetData();
  data.product_code = (String)asset.get('product_code');
  // ... etc ... //
  assets.add(data);
}
```

Comment: How would I handle the data if the array expands with repeating keys? For example more than one product code coming in since there is more than one asset in the array?

Comment: @Richard The `assets` list would contain each asset, including all the product codes. That's the point of the for loop.

Comment: thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a class, instead of separate variables. This is an example with a few of your variables (for reference), plus the list you want to add to:

This would be your class (could be an inner class, if you prefer). Please note that the variable names must match the JSON property names for this code to auto-deserialize.

```
public class JSONDetails() {
    public String sf_ord_num {get;set}
    public Date start_date {get;set}
    <more properties here>
    public List<JSONAssetInfo> asset_info {get;set;}
}

public class JSONAssetInfo() { 
    public String product_code {get;set}
    public String product_descrip {get;set}
    <more properties here>
}
```

Your deserializer would be much simpler, like so:

```
@HttpPost
global static void doPost(String jsonPayload) {
    JSONDetails details = (JSONDetails) JSON.deserialize(jsonPayload, JSONDetails.class);
}
```

You can then find all your variables populated with the contents of the JSON.